# SQL query columns spreading

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I have the following SQL query and as we see in the screenshot, there are two repeating row with the same `constr_id`(2015) value but with different  `assigned_insurance_packages`.

[image]

Query:

```
select  
    ac.constr_id,             
    AIP.NAME as ASSIGNED_INSURANCE_PACKAGES,
    ac.code,ac.constr_name, 
    ac.offer_name,  
    ac.repay_freq,     
    ac.min_amt,        
    ac.max_amt,          
    ac.min_downpay_percent,     
    ac.max_downpay_percent, 
    ac.downpay_amount,        
    ac.min_term,    
    (select 
         listagg(AF.NAME, '; ') within group(order by ACF.CONSTR_ID)  
     from  
         CREDILOGIC.ACQ_CONSTR_FEE acf, CREDILOGIC.ACQ_FEE  af 
     where 
         ACF.CONSTR_ID = AC.CONSTR_ID and AF.FEE_ID = ACF.FEE_ID) as CONSTRUCTION_FEES, 
    INS_COMPANY.SHORT_NAME,
    (select listagg(x.DURATION_MIN || '-' || TO_CHAR(x.RATE_SHIFT, '90.99') || ',' || x.DURATION_MAX || '-' || TO_CHAR(x.RATE_SHIFT, '90.99'), '; ') within group (order by X.CONSTRUCTION_ID)    
     from credilogic.ACQ_CONSTRUCTION_BASERATE x
     where X.CONSTRUCTION_ID = AC.CONSTR_ID) as RATE
from 
    CREDILOGIC.ACQ_CONSTRUCTION ac
left join 
    CREDILOGIC.ACQ_CONSTR_INSPACKAGE aci on ACI.CONSTR_ID = AC.CONSTR_ID 
                                         and ACI.DELETED_TSTAMP is null
left join 
    CREDILOGIC.ACQ_INSURANCE_PACKAGE aip on AIP.INSURANCE_PACKAGE_ID = ACI.INSURANCE_PACKAGE_ID
left join 
    credilogic.ath_party ins_company ON INS_COMPANY.PARTY_ID = aip.PARTY_ID
left join 
    credilogic.ACQ_CONSTRUCTION_DUEDATE  acd on ac.constr_id =  acd.constr_id
left join 
    credilogic.ACQ_APPLICATION acp on ac.constr_id = acp.construction_id
```

I am just going to create two additional columns like `0.3% insurance pack` and `0.5% insurance pack` to put  `ASSIGNED_INSURANCE_PACKAGES`  values into different columns like in the picture below

[image]

Comment: What data goes in those blank spots?

Comment: What kind of database server? SQL Server? Which version? Try looking up pivot

Comment: Yes, it is oracle 11g sql server.

Comment: What's the point of this whole thing? You seem to have duplicated data for each constr_id - once for 0.3% insurance pack and once for 0.5% insurance pack. Why? What does all of that mean? Then - you want to split one column into two, with column names 0.3% insurance pack and 0.5% insurance pack. What needs to go into these two new columns? The data seemed to be exactly the same in the "duplicated" rows (duplicated except the ASSIGNED_INSURANCE_PACKAGES column which you now want to remove).

Comment: It means that to some constr_ids corresponds some amount of insurance_packages. actually, the sample is very simplified . there is about 30 insurance packages  , that is why rows are supposed to be too "duplicated" .  therefore it would better to spread all the 30 packages into at least 4 groups .

Comment: I' ve tried to use group function SUM() this way  `sum(case when AIP.Name LIKE  '%0.3% insurance pack%' then aip.name end) as "0.3% insurance pack"` and added `group by cosntr_id` at the end of the query. but does not seem to work

Comment: So you actually need 30 new columns? This is called a crosstab and is almost always better done in the reporting tool. Humans like crosstabs. Databases don't

Comment: why 30 columns ? Actually, I intended to create three additional columns and spread into them all the 30 types of insurance according certain "case" condition.

Comment: Update your question with the query that includes `sum(case when AIP.Name LIKE  '%0.3% insurance pack%' then aip.name end) as "0.3% insurance pack"` and "des not work" is NOT useful. Did it produce an incorrect result? or an error message? (what was the error?)

Answer (score 0):

If your existing result has 1 row for each insurance pack, and this isn't wanted, then address that issue BEFORE you join the table that causes the unwanted extra row. Here is a cut-down *suggestion* on how this might work for you:

```
SELECT
      ac.constr_id
    , ip.pack_03
    , ip.pack_05
    , ac.code
    , ...

FROM CREDILOGIC.ACQ_CONSTRUCTION ac
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                  ACI.CONSTR_ID
                , max(case when AIP.Name LIKE  '%0.3% insurance pack%' then aip.name end) pack_03
                , max(case when AIP.Name LIKE  '%0.5% insurance pack%' then aip.name end) pack_03
            FROM CREDILOGIC.ACQ_CONSTR_INSPACKAGE ACI
            LEFT JOIN CREDILOGIC.ACQ_INSURANCE_PACKAGE AIP ON AIP.INSURANCE_PACKAGE_ID = ACI.INSURANCE_PACKAGE_ID
                            AND ( AIP.NAME LIKE '%0.3% insurance pack%'
                               OR AIP.NAME LIKE  '%0.5% insurance pack%'
                                )
            WHERE ACI.DELETED_TSTAMP IS NULL
            GROUP BY
                ACI.CONSTR_ID
        ) ip ON ip.CONSTR_ID = AC.CONSTR_ID
```

This is far more efficient than joining all the tables and then attempting to group by all the wanted columns (also complicated by the correlated sub-queries in the select clause). Indeed I would also suggest replacing those correlated sub-queries with joined sub-queries that are grouped if possible.